# Powershell Need to execute two lines

Tags: .net, powershell, wget

I have two commands that need to be executed in PowerShell. Everything else can be down in Batch. I could write the whole thing in PowerShell, but I'd have to make sure the execution policy is set correctly, and that could be a security issue for our netadmins on these servers.

In my Batch script, I need to:

1. Bring down the IIS application cache (I can use AppCmd)
2. Download a new zip file from the server (using my *wget* version of Powershell)
3. Delete all the old files in the www directory
4. Unzip the zip file in the www directory
5. Bring up the IIS application cache.

In Step #2, my two powershell commands are:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("http://path/to/file", "file.name")
```

Is there a way I can combine these two lines into a single Powershell command, much like the way I can in Unix using semicolons? I've tried to put a semicolon between the two lines and get the following error:

```
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:1 char:62
+ $client.DownloadFile(  <<<< http://path/to/file )
   + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (CloseParenToken:TokenId) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

However, inside an actual Powershell script called "wget.ps1", it executes with this:

```
$ powershell -c wget.ps1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://path/to/file", "file.name")
```

Comment: I see! It took me a while to understand what you're doing. You're creating the object and calling the method in one go. Neat trick. I've decided just to write the whole thing in Powershell, and as part of my procedure, change the execution policy. The whole thing makes no sense: What's the use of a powerful language like Powershell over Batch if by default I can't execute scripts? And, if I can simply execute a DOS command line to change the policy, why bother?

Comment: Frustrating and infruriating (sp) are how i would decribe my experience with the executation policy. Esp when incuding remote scripts. Getting it working is good though, and there is plenty with PS.

Comment: Keep an eye out for $(...) type queries too. It's similar to the (..)type used in the answer. Best, matt

Answer (score 1):

Well you have at least two options. The first is to define the execution policy when you run the script. This only changes the policy for the one session that you are kicking off:

```
powershell.exe -File 'C:\Path\To\File.ps1' -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Or you can just pass the commands straight in:

```
powershell.exe -command {$string = 'bobdee';$client.DownloadFile("http://path/to/file", "file.name")}
```

Comment: Putting curly braces doesn't seem to do anything. I tried it with `{foo = "$bar";write-output "Bar = $bar"}` and it just echoed the command. I was only successful if I used double quotes: `"foo = 'bar' ; echo $foo'`. I tried to see if I could find an escape char, but couldn't. The first way, attempting to override execution policy didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

2013 Update:

I'm not sure how things were back in '11, but these days you can do the following in PowerShell:

```
wget "http://path/to/file" -outfile "file.name"
```

Comment: It ended up that this was PS 1.0 and not even PS 2.0. That was one of my issues. I ended up writing the whole thing in PowerShell anyway. It wasn't that difficult to do, and probably been easier if I was familiar with PowerShell.